# Error Installing Podfile Libraries

Tags: ruby, git, bash, cocoapods, git-bash

**What did you do?**

After adding a podfile to the pod nano file, I ran pod install.

**What did you expected to happen?**

I expected the podfile to be downloaded.

**What happened instead?**

Instead I got an error.

**CocoaPods Environment**

The error read

```
Installing SCLAlertView (0.5.8)
[!] Error installing SCLAlertView
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift.git /var/folders/1c/k1hjjv7j0559mz8t6x7dk5bc5k8626/T/d20160528-80617-1w7qaxw --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.5.8

Cloning into '/var/folders/1c/k1hjjv7j0559mz8t6x7dk5bc5k8626/T/d20160528-80617-1w7qaxw'...
```

**Note*** I have already tried running the git command that is failing and I have also tried reinstalling git. Both of these solutions did not work. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have permissions to create `/var/folders/1c/k1h.../T/d20...`?

Comment: I don't know if I have permission. Is there a reason why I would not?

Comment: Usually `/var` is owned by root. And if you are not running `git` as root that's properly the problem, try: `ls -lad /var` and you should see  the owner.

Comment: @andlrc when I type that in I get "lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Jun 25  2015 /var -> private/var" What does that mean?, and if it is the problem then is there a solution?

Comment: Seems like `/var` is symlinked to `/private/var` and you can see the owner is `root` and the group is `wheel`. And only root can write to the directory.

Comment: And since you tagged [tag:git-bash] you will properly don't have `sudo`, so try run git bash as administrator.

Comment: @andlrc I ran sudo git pod install, but I got an error message which read "git: 'pod' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
 add
 log"

Comment: Where did you get `git pod` from?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but I thought you said to run sudo git and then the command I was running, which is pod install.

Comment: `sudo /usr/local/bin/git clone https://....` <- that command as root.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Thanks!

Comment: After I ran sudo /usr/local/bin/git clone https://.... I got this message "remote: Counting objects: 151, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (112/112), done.
remote: Total 151 (delta 32), reused 123 (delta 22), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (151/151), 1.20 MiB | 77.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (32/32), done.
Checking connectivity... done.", and ran pod install but the same error keeps comming up.

Comment: Now you have cloned the repo to `/var/folders/1c/k1hjjv7j0559mz8t6x7dk5bc5k8626/T/d20160528-80617-1w7qaxw`. From there you need to consider if thats the location you want it in or not. And also note that: Quote from [repo](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift): `Beautiful animated Alert View. Written in Swift` Are you sure you are cloning the correct repo?

Comment: How do I clone the repo into that location?, and also I am sure I am cloning the correct repo.

Comment: You just did with the `git clone ...` command

Comment: Then why is it still not working when I run pod install?

Comment: Just because you clone a repo you don't magically get a command. You will need to add the directory the command is in to your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: @andlrc I really appreciate your help so far. I am very new to this, so I hope this is not a stupid question, but what exactly is the command I should write? (what is my $PATH variable?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you do not have permissions to write to `/var`, try:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/git clone https://...
```

You can check the permissions with:

```
ls -ld /var
```

And since you taggged [git-bash](/questions/tagged/git-bash) you might need to run git bash as administrator.